# NodeJS read query from POSTMAN but API doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I'm trying to get the min and max values based on queries.
I'm using the following logic,

```
if(req.query.max_price && req.query.max_price != '' && req.query.max_price != 'any'){
  qry.price = { $lte: req.query.max_price};
}
// and 
if(req.query.min_price && req.query.min_price != '' && req.query.min_price != 'any'){
  qry.price = { $gte: req.query.min_price};
}
```

but I can't seem to get the right response make a request something like the following,

```
http://localhost:5000/api/ads/list?offset=0&limit=2&min _price=200&max_price=3000
```

I think there's something wrong with logic, but I can't seem to pin where the problem is.

Comment: Please tell us what is the error. There's a space at min _price is that intentional? Did u console.log(req.query) before posting this question on SO?

Comment: That is a typo during posting this question. That is not a problem. When a make a request with max_price=80, I get 100, and all values below 80. And if I set min_price=200&max_price=4500, I get all the values below 4500.

Comment: i.e, when I use both parameters together, I get whatever parameter runs last.

Comment: is req.query correct?

Comment: I did console.log and as I said, I get whatever parameter runs last,

Comment: yes, req.query is correct.

Comment: why would this logic work in postman if it doesn't work if you access it directly? Because you are overwriting qry.price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overwriting the qry.price. It should be,

```
qry.price = {}

    if(req.query.max_price && req.query.max_price != '' && req.query.max_price != 'any'){
        qry.price = { ...qry.price, $lte: req.query.max_price};
    }


if(req.query.min_price && req.query.min_price != '' && req.query.min_price != 'any'){
        qry.price = { ...qry.price, $gte: req.query.min_price};
    }
```